# "Oft schon habe ich dich von Herzen bedauert, dass du Tag für Tag die schwersten Lasten tragen und vom Morgen bis Abend arbeiten musst."

Tags: sentence-structure, accusative

What is the standard grammatical (syntactic) treatment of a sentence like this, which is from [an Aesop](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/fabeln-9534/64).

> Oft schon habe ich **dich** von Herzen bedauert, **dass** du Tag für Tag die schwersten Lasten tragen und vom Morgen bis Abend arbeiten musst.

I note that both *dich* and the *dass*-clause are sorts of things that could be an accusative object of *bedauern.*

See e.g. these from [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/bedauern):

> **jemanden** bedauern: feel sorry for sb.
>   ich bedauere sehr, **dass**: I very much regret that.

I know what the Aesop sentence means.  I am looking for grammatical treatment.  For example:

- *jemanden* is the accusative object of *bedauern* in 'jemanden bedauern'.
- The *dass*-clause is the accusative object of *bedauere* in 'ich bedauere sehr, dass...'
- In the Aesop sentence, both *dich* and the *dass*-clause are accusative objects of *bedauert*.
- In such a case, *dich* is said to be a [SOME GRAMMATICAL TERM], the *dass*-clause an [ANOTHER GRAMMATICAL TERM], and *bedauert* a [THIRD GRAMMATICAL TERM].

I am not saying that the above bullets are right.  They are meant to illustrate the sort of answer I am looking for. Thanks.

I am not sure, but [this other post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53400/da%C3%9F-er-sich-was-seine-wahrnehmung-betraf-auf-keine-bestimmte-zahl-festlegen-m) may be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

German conjunctions tend to be polysemous in confusing ways. Yes, *dass* introduces complement clauses, but it also serves to introduce adverbial clauses designating a result, purpose or reason. See the DWDS entry for [dass](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dass), 5. (although some of the examples are poorly chosen).

> das Publikum tobte, dass die Wände wackelten
> *the audience cheered so that the walls shook*
>
> Schreib das auf, dass du es nicht vergisst!
> *Write that down so that you don't forget it!*
>
> Bist du etwa hierhergerannt, dass du so schwitzt? ([source](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=_Uz3AAAAQBAJ&q=%22dass+du+so+schwitzt%22))
> *Did you run here? I'm asking because you're sweating like that.*

In your example, a causal interpretation of the *dass* clause would fit. Note that this use is mostly obsolete; it is alive and well in the example I gave above, where the subordinate clause is not interpreted as a *cause for running*, but as *a cause for asking a question about running*.

Comment: "das Publikum tobte, dass die Wände wackelten" - ist da ein "so" weggelassen?

Comment: @Dan Der Beispielsatz soll ohne *so* sein, um zu zeigen, daß *daß* auch für sich konsekutive Bedeutung haben kann.